# Increament the particular value using update query

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select top 1(SUBSTRING(patientid,9,4)) as MaxpatientID from Patient_Data
where PatientID like 'AT112013%' order by PatientID desc;
```

Which gives the result as

```
MaxPatientID
0014
```

Now is there any possibility of increment this number as for ex:

```
0015
0016
0017
```

I tried this query but its not worth useful

```
update Patient_Data  set (top 1(SUBSTRING(patientid,9,4)) as MaxpatientID)=(MaxpatientID + 1)
where PatientID like 'AT112013%' order by PatientID desc;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a regular INT IDENTITY but then just show the extra zeroes when displaying on your front end? Or perhaps a second (calculated) column which uses your identity column and adds the zeroes you're looking for?

Comment: You need to update top 1 row only? or what??

Comment: he is updating all record with PatientID like 'AT112013%'

Comment: For every transaction i need to increment the value

Comment: Is this will increment during insertion of record or updating, looks like your sample is updating. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
update patientid = SUBSTRING(patientid,0,9)) + convert(varchar(32), convert(int, SUBSTRING(patientid,9,4)) + 1) where patientid like 'AT112013%'
```

Comment: Note that the sample incremented value is not padded with zero/s

Answer (score 0):

I just tried out in mysql. Hope this matches your requirement:

```
UPDATE test SET patientId = (SELECT patientId
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(patientId, 1, 6), CAST(SUBSTRING(patientId, 4, 2) AS UNSIGNED) +1) 
    FROM test
    WHERE `patientId` LIKE 'AT112013%') AS temp
)
```